# Google drive insufficient permissions for a file

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying use Java to publish a folder on Google drive. I found and tried [this code](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/publish-site)

But I get the error as below :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "file.permissions",
    "locationType" : "other",
    "message" : "Insufficient permissions for this file",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient permissions for this file"
}
```

My access type is offline and scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and my client is a web application.

add my code :

```
 private static String CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  public String auth_code = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  public String accessToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  Credential credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                         .setTransport(httpTransport).setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET).build();

  credentials.setAccessToken(accessToken);
  credentials.setRefreshToken(refreshToken);

  Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,   credential).setApplicationName("reports").build();

  Permission permission = new Permission();
  permission.setValue("");
  permission.setType("anyone");
  permission.setRole("reader");
  service.permissions().insert(fileID, permission).execute();
```

the error orror at last line

Comment: The error means that you don't have access to create the folder where ever it is you are trying to create it.

Comment: Hi, DalmTo , the the folder can create successfully, the error happened when I change the permission .

Comment: Then you don't have permissions to change the change the permissions to the directory.    Check the permissions you authenticated with.  Check the owner of the drive account (especially if you are using a service account)  check that you are correctly using authentication.

Comment: I don't use service account , I use we application . how to check the permission?

Comment: enable logging and post the http request

Comment: Wheres the code? Without code few will help

Comment: I add the code ,anybody can help check where is wrong?

Comment: Did you fins an answer for this?